# Adding a background image to a <div> element

Tags: html

Is it possible to make a `<div>` element contain a background image, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You mean this?

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('../images/divbg.png');
}
</style>

...

<div class="bgimg">
    div with background
</div>
```

Comment: can I set it non-repeatable?

Comment: yes: background-repeat: no-repeat; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Answer (score 47):

You can do that using CSS's [`background`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) propieties. There are few ways to do it:

---

### By ID

**HTML:**
`<div id="div-with-bg"></div>`

**CSS**:

```
#div-with-bg
{
    background: color url('path') others;
}
```

---

### By Class

**HTML:**
`<div class="div-with-bg"></div>`

**CSS**:

```
.div-with-bg
{
    background: color url('path') others;
}
```

---

### In HTML (which is evil)

**HTML:**
`<div style="background: color url('path')"></div>`

---

**Where**:

- *color* is color in hex or one from [*X11 Colors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names)
- *path* is path to the image
- *others* like position, attachament

---

`background` CSS Property is a connection of all background-xxx propieties in that syntax:

**background**: 
*background-color* 
*background-image* 
*background-repeat* 
*background-attachment* 
*background-position*;

Source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: I want to use the HTML method, but is it possible, by only using that method, to add 2 images that are differently situated. I  know it is possible to do something like:background-image: url("image.jpg"), url("image2"); but doing this, both images will be in the same place, kinda "overlaying" each other, and I want to set different positions for them.

Answer (score 36):

**Yes**:

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/image.gif); height: 400px; width: 400px;">Text here</div>
```

Answer (score 27):

**Use this style to get a centered background image without repeat.**

```
.bgImgCenter{
    background-image: url('imagePath');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    position: relative;
}
```

In HTML, set this style for your div:

```
<div class="bgImgCenter"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use like ..

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">Example of a DIV element with a background image:</div>
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"> </div>
```

Comment: Surely the path should be in single quotes??

Answer (score 10):

You can simply add an img src Attribute with id:

```
<body>
<img id="backgroundimage" src="bgimage.jpg" border="0" alt="">
</body>
```

and in your CSS file (stretch background):

```
#backgroundimage
{
   height: auto;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 674px;
   padding: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: The question is about adding a background element to a div, not adding a seperate img attribute so this does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: While this solution doesn't properly answer the question, it did give me an idea for another issue I was facing so for that I offer my thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="foo">Foo Bar</div>
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.foo {
    background-image: url("images/foo.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="image">Example to have Background Image</div>
```

We need to Add the below content in Style tag:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url('C:\Users\ajai\Desktop\10.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Your local path: C:\Users\ajai\Desktop\10.jpg is never going to work online ;)

Comment: Just for shake i give this path

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the method is the same as setting the whole body

```
.divi{
    background-image: url('path');
}

</style>

<div class="divi"></div>
```