# How to set a background inside a div

Tags: html, css

Final resulting background image that I need:

[image: Resulting background image]

Background image that I have used:

[image: Original background image]

But I have got this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpB7R/10/)**

**::Summary of Fiddle::**

HTML...

```
<div id="top-part">
<div id="topmost">
    <div id="top-most" class="wrapper">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="topmenu" class="wrapper">

</div>
```

CSS...

```
.wrapper{
      position: relative;
      width: 943px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
#top-part{
      background: url(img/bg-header-effects.png) no-repeat top center;
}
#topmost{
      background: #900;
      opacity: 0.8;
}
#top-most{
      height: 139px;
}
#topmenu{
      background: #900;
      opacity: 0.8;
      height: 51px;
      border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Background Image of a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604859/background-image-of-a-div-element)

Comment: Seting background image inside the top-part (topmost and topmenu)

Comment: @Boaz- Hey! this is not a duplicate as your link

Comment: See my updated question that may let you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKX2B/)**

html...

```
<div id="top-part">
  <div id="topmost">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="top-menu" class="wrapper">
  <div id="topmenu">
  </div>
</div>
```

css...

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative; 
    width: 943px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-part{
   background: url(img/bg-header-effects.png) no-repeat top center;
}
#topmost{
   background: #900; 
   opacity: 0.8; 
   height: 139px;
}
#top-menu{
   background: url(img/bg-header-effects.png) no-repeat 50% 45%; 
   border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
#topmenu{
   background: #900; 
   opacity: 0.8; 
   height: 51px; 
   border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

## Update - to cover your recent edit

```
#header{

    background: #f00 url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWVfL.jpg');
    opacity: .6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 189px;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpB7R/5/)

---

You could try using the `background` property in CSS:

```css
div{
    background: url('path_to_your_image.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

[Learn more about using the `background-image` property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image)

**Note:**

There is a difference between `background` and `background-image`. In this answer I've used the `background` property which basically takes all of the possible options for a background image in CSS and lets them be used in a single call.

For example, you could split the above up into two selectors:

```css
div{
    background-image: url('path_to_your_image.jpg') no-repeat; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Since w3schools is deprecated in SO, here's another link that would be better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image

Comment: @Passerby It will not let me post that link any ideas why?

Comment: I couldn't achieve what I wanted coz I think my question is unclear? Please See updated question.

Comment: I think no-one has understood my problem so I have updated with a fiddle. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: @user2253835 I think the easiest way (if you don't want to go the route below) would be to use photoshop to just white out the bottom parts, and create a single image :) Then you don't have to use two images and create this big work around.

Comment: @Evan What I wanted to know I got that from C-link.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach that I'm thinking of is having a picture within divs covering the whole page. The code will be very simple, but the only downside is the image may be warped or it can be clicked on unless you have this.

HTML:

```
<div id="backgroundcolor">
            <div id="backgroundimage">
                </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#backgroundcolor {
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
}
#backgroundimage {
    background: ("http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/infocus/election110712/s_e01_37923312.jpg");
    resize: none;
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: initial;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. Please could you show me a demo.