# Bootstrap 3 - Jumbotron background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I am having trouble setting a background image for bootstrap jumbotrons. My main.css comes after the bootstrap css and I am selecting the jumbotron using a class called "banner" which is in the same div as the jumbotron, but it still doesn't work. Here is my code...

HTML:

```
  <!-- Banner -->
  <div class="jumbotron banner">
    <div class="container">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>
          Bits king
        </h1>
        <h2>
          Web Design &amp; Development
        </h2>
      </hgroup>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .banner {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 20%;
  min-width: 30%;
  background-image: url("../assets/images/banner.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Works in this code pen.. make sure that your path to the image is correct. What's the browser console say? http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/oYZMdr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a background image to a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604859/adding-a-background-image-to-a-div-element)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `background-image` property to the `.jumbotron` class in your custom css file (Make sure you reference your custom css file **after** Bootstrap. Here's an example:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("/img/your-image.jpg");
    background-color: #17234E;
    margin-bottom: 0;`enter code here`
    min-height: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I actually solved this issue, I had to upload my image to MediaFire and link it in the CSS from there. For some reason previously it didn't let me use the local image. But thank you, this would be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

add "jumbotron-custom" to class attribute and apply this after "bootstrap" css :

```
.jumdotron-custom
{
    background: url('/*background url*/') no-repeat !important;
}
```

..or just add !important to your 'background-image' of css.

Comment: That is what I did basically, I added the "banner" class to the jumbotron div

Comment: did you add !important after your background property?

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning. Try this:

```
background-image: url("../assets/images/banner.jpg");
```

Let me know if it works or not?

Comment: thats exactly what I did in the CSS code, sorry for not replying sooner. Stack Overflow apparently decided to stop sending me emails for some odd reason lol