# HTML - Add a background image to a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website with a header that stretches across the top, and i want this header to have a background image... But, I can't work out how to do it... I've tried plenty of techniques I have found on stack overflow but haven't been able to get any of them to work. 
Below is my code for the header section:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="color:#ffffff">
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <p>SUBHEADING</p> 
</div>
```

Any help on how I can give this div a background image will be much appreciated!

(also sorry in advance, I'm an absolute HTML noob)

Comment: Post your CSS code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a background image to a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604859/adding-a-background-image-to-a-div-element)

Comment: Searching for your title [html Add a background image to a div](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+Add+a+background+image+to+a+div) gives over 2000 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a background on div is easy, do it like

Style

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
}
</style>
```

Html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center bgimg" style="color:#ffffff">
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <p>SUBHEADING</p> 
</div>
```

Give `.bgimg` css class to div and you can see the background