# how to set a dynamic (streamed) image as background to a div tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

how to set a dynamic image as background to a div tag, I an using primefaces with spark layout.

```
    <div class="Container100 " id="spark-highlight" 
     style="padding:10rem 0px; background-image: ...">
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Adding a background image to a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604859/adding-a-background-image-to-a-div-element)

Comment: not duplicated, please read dinamic image.

Comment: You can stream the dynamic image vua a servlet and use it in a url like in the duplicate (or almost in ypur question) just break down your question in manageable parts